# How to change the background color in HTML code through SQL query

Tags: html, sql

I have SQL query which sends out an email to user to log in. But now i have a request on how make the LOG IN button much more visible and make it highlighted in blue bluebackground and the text to white.

This is my code:

```
OPEN Email_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM Email_cursor  INTO @RecipientsList,@FirstName,@LastName,@ID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
 
 SET @MessageBody = 'Hello, ' + +'<br><br>You have a new message in the  portal. Please 
 <a href="https://psdhkgdksportal/"> <u>login </u></a>
to view the message. If you do not have a portal account,  possible to update your communication preferences. <br><br>'

+'Please note: This is an automated message; do not reply to this message. 

+'<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img width=800 height=500 id="1" src="cid:Psiem.png">
    </body>
</html>'
+'Sincerely, <br>'
```

And this is how it displays in the email:
[image]

And this is how i want to change the login ([image] button

how do i change the HTML code to add the background color?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to change the HTML code of the link and replace it by a button. There are different possibilities to implement email HTML buttons, see e.g. https://www.litmus.com/blog/a-guide-to-bulletproof-buttons-in-email-design/ for a nice overview. I've picked the last option from there:

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#17202a; color:antiquewhite; font-family: Arial">

    Hello,<br/><br/>

    You have a new message in the  portal. Please 
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-radius: 3px;" bgcolor=" #85c1e9" align="center">
                    <a href="https://psdhkgdksportal/" target="_blank"
                       style="font-size: 24px; 
                              font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                              font-weight: bold;  
                              color: #17202a; 
                              text-decoration: none; 
                              border-radius: 3px; 
                              padding: 18px 18px; 
                              border: 1px solid  #154360; 
                              display: inline-block;">
                      Visit Now!
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
       
    to view the message. If you do not have a portal account,  possible to update    your communication preferences. <br/><br/>

    Please note: This is an automated message; do not reply to this message. <br/>   

    <img id="1" src="cid:Psiem.png" width="800" height="500">
    <br/><br/>
    Sincerely,<br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is an example, just change the colors, font, etc. as you like.

You then only have to add this to your `SET @MessageBody` statement.